# Difference between using Jquery to add button, and explicitly adding it in HTML when calling functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a beginner in HTML/Javascript and know basically no Jquery. I was playing around with npm packages, Jquery, and function calls when I stumbled across a problem.

If I add a button using Jquery and attach an on click function with it, I am able to alert the user of something once the button is clicked.

If I add another button using HTML, I am not able to alert the user of the same thing once the button is clicked.

I have tried two methods of calling the alert() function when adding buttons with HTML, both with no successes while the Jquery button adding works perfectly fine.

Why is this the case? And how do I make the HTML explicitly defined buttons work with function calls?

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="bundle.js" charset="="utf-8""></script>
        <button onclick="fnClick()" id="my-button2">my-button2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery')
var curvematcher = require('curve-matcher')

const curve1 = [{x: 2, y: 1.5}, {x: 42222, y: 3444}];
const curve2 = [{x: 2, y: 1.5}, {x: 0, y: 0} ];


var button = $('<button/>').html('my-button1').on('click', function() {
    alert(curvematcher.shapeSimilarity(curve1, curve2))
})
$('body').append(button)

function fnClick() {
    alert(curvematcher.shapeSimilarity(curve1, curve2));
}

document.getElementById("my-button2").onclick = function () { alert(curvematcher.shapeSimilarity(curve1, curve2)); };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the content to be rendered before attaching the onclick callback (I'd suggest you use `addEventListener('click'` instead)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("my-button2").addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(curvematcher.shapeSimilarity(curve1, curve2));
  });
})
```

Comment: I tried this, and all that happened is the first button was removed. After trying to click on this button, nothing happens. I also tried editing the HTML of the button to not include 
`onclick="fnClick()"`

Comment: Also, why doesn't the Jquery approach not need to wait for the button to be loaded before adding the on click functionality?

Comment: Apparently there is a parsing error at the end of the javascript file, which is causing the error? Is there a syntactical issue with parentheses?

Comment: I'd suggest you create a shareable project in codepen.io or jsfiddle.net, that would make it easier to understand your problem and reproduce it.